# Logstash: TestResult comes out as an array

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

The generated results of running the config below show the TestResult section as an array. I am trying to get rid of that array to make sending the data to Elasticsearch.

I have the following XML file:

```
<tem:SubmitTestResult xmlns:tem="http://www.example.com" xmlns:acs="http://www.example.com" xmlns:acs1="http://www.example.com">   
   <tem:LabId>123</tem:LabId>
   <tem:userId>123</tem:userId>
   <tem:TestResult>
      <acs:CreatedBy>123</acs:CreatedBy>
      <acs:CreatedDate>123</acs:CreatedDate>
      <acs:LastUpdatedBy>123</acs:LastUpdatedBy>
      <acs:LastUpdatedDate>123</acs:LastUpdatedDate>
      <acs1:Capacity95FHigh>123</acs1:Capacity95FHigh>
      <acs1:Capacity95FHigh_AHRI>123</acs1:Capacity95FHigh_AHRI>
      <acs1:CondensateDisposal_AHRI>123</acs1:CondensateDisposal_AHRI>
      <acs1:DegradationCoeffCool>123</acs1:DegradationCoeffCool>
   </tem:TestResult>
</tem:SubmitTestResult>
```

And I am using this config:

```
input {
    file {
        path => "/var/log/logstash/test3.xml"
    }
}
filter {
    multiline {
        pattern => "<tem:SubmitTestResult>"
        negate => "true"
        what => "previous"
    }

    if "multiline" in [tags] {
        mutate {
            gsub => ["message", "\n", ""]
        }

        mutate {
            replace => ["message", '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>%{message}']
        }

        xml {
            source => "message"
            target => "SubmitTestResult"
        }

        mutate {
            remove_field => ["message", "@version", "host", "@timestamp", "path", "tags", "type"]
            remove_field => ["[SubmitTestResult][xmlns:tem]","[SubmitTestResult][xmlns:acs]","[SubmitTestResult][xmlns:acs1]"]
        }

        mutate {
             replace => [ "[SubmitTestResult][LabId]", "%{[SubmitTestResult][LabId]}" ]
             replace => [ "[SubmitTestResult][userId]", "%{[SubmitTestResult][userId]}" ]
        }

        mutate {
            replace => [ "[SubmitTestResult][TestResult][0][CreatedBy]", "%{[SubmitTestResult][TestResult][0][CreatedBy]}" ]
            replace => [ "[SubmitTestResult][TestResult][0][CreatedDate]", "%{[SubmitTestResult][TestResult][0][CreatedDate]}" ]
            replace => [ "[SubmitTestResult][TestResult][0][LastUpdatedBy]", "%{[SubmitTestResult][TestResult][0][LastUpdatedBy]}" ]
            replace => [ "[SubmitTestResult][TestResult][0][LastUpdatedDate]", "%{[SubmitTestResult][TestResult][0][LastUpdatedDate]}" ]
            replace => [ "[SubmitTestResult][TestResult][0][Capacity95FHigh]", "%{[SubmitTestResult][TestResult][0][Capacity95FHigh]}" ]
            replace => [ "[SubmitTestResult][TestResult][0][Capacity95FHigh_AHRI]", "%{[SubmitTestResult][TestResult][0][Capacity95FHigh_AHRI]}" ]
            replace => [ "[SubmitTestResult][TestResult][0][CondensateDisposal_AHRI]", "%{[SubmitTestResult][TestResult][0][CondensateDisposal_AHRI]}" ]
            replace => [ "[SubmitTestResult][TestResult][0][DegradationCoeffCool]", "%{[SubmitTestResult][TestResult][0][DegradationCoeffCool]}" ]
        }
    }
}
output {
    stdout {
        codec => "rubydebug"
    }
}
```

The result is:

```
"SubmitTestResult" => {
             "LabId" => "123",
            "userId" => "123",
        "TestResult" => [
            [0] {
                              "CreatedBy" => "123",
                            "CreatedDate" => "123",
                          "LastUpdatedBy" => "123",
                        "LastUpdatedDate" => "123",
                        "Capacity95FHigh" => "123",
                   "Capacity95FHigh_AHRI" => "123",
                "CondensateDisposal_AHRI" => "123",
                   "DegradationCoeffCool" => "123"
            }
        ]
    }
```

As you can see, `TestResult` has the "[0]" array in there. Is there some config change I can do to make sure that it doesn't come out as an array? I want to send this to Elasticsearch and want the data correct.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. After the last `mutate` block, I added one more mutate block. All I had to do was rename the field and that did the trick.

```
mutate {
    rename => {"[SubmitTestResult][TestResult][0]" => "[SubmitTestResult][TestResult]"}
}
```

The result now looks proper:

```
"SubmitTestResult" => {
         "LabId" => "123",
        "userId" => "123",
    "TestResult" => {
                      "CreatedBy" => "123",
                    "CreatedDate" => "123",
                  "LastUpdatedBy" => "123",
                "LastUpdatedDate" => "123",
                "Capacity95FHigh" => "123",
           "Capacity95FHigh_AHRI" => "123",
        "CondensateDisposal_AHRI" => "123",
           "DegradationCoeffCool" => "123"
    }
}
```